# How to print image in java

Tags: java, image

How can we print a buffered image in java?
We can send FileInputStream to Print Service, but i need to send buffered Image to it.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("YOurImageFileName.PNG");
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);
job.print(doc, pras);
```

Is it possible?

Check the complete code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PrintanImagetoprintdirectly.htm).

Comment: A similar question was already asked in StackOverflow, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338423/print-a-image-with-actual-size-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
                if (pageIndex != 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }
                graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
                return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
});     
try {
    printJob.print();
} catch (PrinterException e1) {             
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iText library.. there is a simple example to print an Image to pdf .

[Adding an IText Image to a PDF document](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html)