# Print Stage with JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I found some basic example how to print web page with JavaFX but I'm looking for examplewhich can print the complete Scene with app content. Is there any example?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789449/export-stage-into-pdf/22796964#22796964)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your scene to an image using

```
WritableImage snapshot = scene.snapshot(null);
```

This will return a WritableImage, which can be converted to an Image File or BufferedImage, and print using the Printing API of JavaFX8 (there are not lot of examples available for this, but the new API has quite a resemblance to the old Printing API, so it won't be a problem)

*Converting WritableImage to Png File*

```
WritableImage snapshot = scene.snapshot(null);
File file = new File("image.png");
try {
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null), "png", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Converting WritableImage to BufferedImage* (used for printing)

```
WritableImage snapshot = scene.snapshot(null);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
```

For just a small example of how to print an Image using java, please go through

[Proper way of printing a BufferedImage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404553/proper-way-of-printing-a-bufferedimage-in-java)

[How to print image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479621/how-to-print-image-in-java)