# printing barcode using java

Tags: java, servlets

i am trying to print barcode using servlet but the print is not in proper size. i want to print label with specific with and height. if i am print this barcode using 3rd party application it's printing correct but if i use my code print become twice in size use more then one label.

```
package com.service;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.int2of5.Interleaved2Of5Bean;
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.output.bitmap.BitmapCanvasProvider;

/**
 *
 * @author akash
 */
public class Barcode extends HttpServlet {
    private String filePath = "/home/chimeralabs/public_html/uploads/";
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

            String id = request.getParameter("patientId");

           Interleaved2Of5Bean bean = new Interleaved2Of5Bean();

    bean.setHeight(10d);

    bean.doQuietZone(false);

    OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(new File("Barcode_"+id+".png"));

    BitmapCanvasProvider provider =
        new BitmapCanvasProvider(out, "image/x-png", 510,
                                 BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, false,
                                 0);
    bean.generateBarcode(provider, id);

    provider.finish();

    BufferedImage barcodeImage = provider.getBufferedImage();
    response.setContentType("image/x-png");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(barcodeImage, "png", outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    request.setAttribute("patientId", id);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Print");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

[image]

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Print extends HttpServlet {
    private String filePath = "/home/chimeralabs/public_html/uploads/";

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));

    String id = (String)request.getAttribute("patientId");

    PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);

    PrintService ps = pss[0];
    System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);

    DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Barcode_1082.png");
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);

       try {
           job.print(doc, pras);
       } catch (PrintException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Print.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

    fin.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: i may be mistaken, but isnt the size determined by the jsp that displays it? meaning, it would have to be set in the height  and width parameters of the jsp?

Comment: i think you are write.

Comment: from what is given, i don't think ill be able to help you- i would need more context. good luck mate.

Comment: i am updating the code wait

Comment: i added the code for barcode generation also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since I can't comment yet, I guess I have to leave this as an answer?)

I'm not too familiar with Java printing, but it looks like the file you're trying to print is a PNG, but the `DocFlavor` is set to `GIF`. There seems to be a [PNG](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.html#PNG) `DocFlavor`. Have you tried that?

Also, you might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338423/print-a-image-with-actual-size-in-java) which seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

The iText library supports pretty much every kind of barcode imaginable. You can use the same.

Answer (score 0):

Include this jar [BixolonPrinter.jar](https://github.com/Fewlaps/bixolon-printer-example/tree/master/app/libs) file and 
`BarCodeBuilder.getBarCodeData(data, symbology, height, width, alignment, textPosition)` which retuns byte[] to be given to printer. which supports all formats of barcodes and sizes.

```
// ------------------- Barcode Symbology ------------------- //
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_UPCA = 101;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_UPCE = 102;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_EAN8 = 103;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_EAN13 = 104;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_ITF = 106;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_Codabar = 107;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_Code39 = 108;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_Code93 = 109;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_Code128 = 110;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_PDF417 = 201;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_MAXICODE = 202;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_DATAMATRIX = 203;
public static int BARCODE_TYPE_QRCODE = 204;

// ------------------- Barcode Text Position------------------- //
public static int BARCODE_HRI_NONE = -11;
public static int BARCODE_HRI_ABOVE = -12;
public static int BARCODE_HRI_BELOW = -13;
```